# httpWebRequest post in combination Of xml & string & integer key values and contenettype = application/json in c# visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net

when **xmlcontents** fill with ***string*** i have a successful post BUT when i fill **xmlcontents**  ***with XML***. server will turn back 400 : BAD REQUEST

```
    private void btnHttpPostNo2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtResponsedString.Text = string.Empty;
        lblHttpClientResponse.Text = string.Empty;
        txtPostedString.Text = string.Empty;




        string webAddr = https://peyvand.herokuapp.com/api/send/;

            strFilename = "XMLTest.xml";


            XmlDocument xmlPostDoc = ReadXml(@"C:\ReplDir\Wlst", strFilename);


            string xmlcontents; 

            using (var buf = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(buf, Encoding.ASCII))
                    xmlPostDoc.Save(writer);
                txtEncodedXml.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf.ToArray());
                xmlcontents = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf.ToArray());
            }

            if (xmlcontents == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NULL XML recieved");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(xmlcontents);
            }




            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            string strFileContent = "";
            string json = "{" + '"' + "entries" + '"' + ":[{ " + '"' + "filename" + '"' + " : " + '"' + strFilename + '"'

                + " , " + '"' + "content" + '"' + " : " + '"' + xmlcontents + '"'
                + " , " + '"' + "subscriber" + '"' + " : " + '"' + "Te" + '"'
                + " , " + '"' + "distributor" + '"' + " : " + '"' + "T1" + '"'
                + " , " + '"' + "subjecttype" + '"' + " : " + "1"
                + " , " + '"' + "clientid" + '"' + " : " + '"' + "123uploading client identifier" + '"' + " }]}";


            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                txtPostedString.Text = json;
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                txtResponsedString.Text = responseText;

                txtStatusCode.Text =  httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString();
            }
    }
```

when xmlcontents fill with string i have a successful post BUT when i fill xmlcontents  with XML server will turn back 400 : BAD REQUEST

Comment: I assume you're matching the `Content-type` to the type of data you're sending? Perhaps you could use a tool like Fiddler to examine exactly what you're sending to the server.

Comment: thanks for your response : when i fill xmlcontent with content of a xml file will recieve : System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Comment: i guess there is a problem with ending type of my .xml file contenets